# Display a dynamic message on p:confirmDialog without sending a request to the server

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I need to display a confirmation message dynamically on `<p:confirmDialog>`. This can be done by updating this component with AJAX after sending the request to the server. For example,

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple">
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton oncomplete="confirmDeleteMultiple.show()"
                         update=":form:confirmDialogDeleteMultiple" 
                         process=":form:dataTable"
                         actionListener="#{bean.deleteMultipleActionListener}"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

The specified button on the footer of `<p:dataTable>` can update the message which is set inside `deleteMultipleActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent){...}` and updates the specified confirm dialog, `confirmDialogDeleteMultiple` which is as follows.

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialogDeleteMultiple"
                 widgetVar="confirmDeleteMultiple"
                 message="#{bean.deleteMultipleMsg}"
                 header="Header Message"
                 appendToBody="true" closable="true">

    <p:commandButton id="confirmDeleteMultiple"
                     value="Yes"
                     process="@this dataTable messages"
                     rendered="#{bean.renderedYesButtonMultipleDelete}" 
                     update="messages dataTable" 
                     oncomplete="confirmDeleteMultiple.hide()"
                     actionListener="#{bean.deleteMultiple}"/>

    <p:commandButton id="declineDeleteMultiple"
                     value="#{bean.noButtonTextMultipleDelete}" 
                     onclick="confirmDeleteMultiple.hide()"
                     type="button"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

The managed bean simply looks like the following.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public final class Bean {
    private String deleteMultipleMsg; //Getter only.
    private boolean renderedYesButtonMultipleDelete=true; //Getter only.
    private String noButtonTextMultipleDelete="No"; //Getter only.

    public void deleteMultipleActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(selectedValues!=null&&!selectedValues.isEmpty()) {
            renderedYesButtonMultipleDelete=true;
            noButtonTextMultipleDelete="No";
            deleteMultipleMsg="Confirmation message.";
        } else {
            noButtonTextMultipleDelete="Ok";
            renderedYesButtonMultipleDelete=false;
            deleteMultipleMsg="Row selection message.";
        }
    }
}
```

`selectedValues` is a List which holds the selected rows in `DataTable`. `deleteMultipleMsg` is a message that is displayed on `<p:confirmDialog>` after an AJAX request.

---

There is no question at all about it. This works as expected. Therefore, I don't explore this at length.

This however, requires sending an AJAX request to the server just to fetch a simple confirm message. I feel this is quite unnecessary. Such a confirmation message should be displayed on the client-side itself before sending the actual request to the server.

So, I'm looking for a way to do this on the client-side itself probably by using usual JavaScript. Can this simply be done as usual, exactly as JavaScript `confirm("Message")` with `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons is displayed?

<s>I'm using Primefaces 3.5.</s> <s>Now it is 4.0 final.</s> Now it is 5.1 final.

Answer (score 1):

May be simple [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) function is enough for you:

```
<script>
jQuery("confirmDeleteMultiple.p").replaceWith(...

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the message in your XHTML page with the CSS style `display:none` and do the validation in JavaScript and if the validation fails just change the style to `display:block`.
No AJAX.

Comment: The rows to be deleted should be counted first on client-side that asks the user for a confirmation like, "*You're about to delete 5 rows...*" before the actual AJAX request to delete the selected row(s) is sent. Therefore, I'm not sure how to achieve this by using JavaScript. I'm using checkboxes to mark the rows for deletion but actually checkboxes are not rendered. They are displayed just by using some `<div>` and alike.